Timeout when waiting for 3rd party check iframe message in Angular app with Keycloak on Docker
I'm trying to deploy an Angular application with Keycloak authentication using Docker. The setup works fine on my local machine (using localhost), but when I deploy it to an Ubuntu VM, I get the following error in the browser console when accessing http://192.168.1.105:4200:
{error: 'Timeout when waiting for 3rd party check iframe message.'}

Here's my docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  angular:
    build:
      context: ./web/jtekt-client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4200:80"

  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql-db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: jtekt
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  jtekt-server:
    build: ./server/jtekt-server
    container_name: jtekt-server
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-db:3306/jtekt
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
    depends_on:
      mysql-db:
        condition: service_healthy

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.0
    container_name: keycloak
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    command: start-dev


Here's the KeycloakService in my Angular app:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
import { UserProfile } from '../models/user-profile';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class KeycloakService {
  private _keycloak: Keycloak | undefined;
  private _profile: UserProfile | undefined;

  get keycloak() {
    if (!this._keycloak) {
      this._keycloak = new Keycloak({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.105:8080',
        realm: 'jtekt',
        clientId: 'jtekt',
      });
    }
    return this._keycloak;
  }

  get profile(): UserProfile | undefined {
    return this._profile;
  }

  constructor() {}

  async init() {
    console.log('Authentication the user...');
    const authenticated = await this.keycloak?.init({
      onLoad: 'login-required',
    });
    if (authenticated) {
      this._profile = (await this.keycloak?.loadUserProfile()) as UserProfile;
    }
  }

  login() {
    return this.keycloak?.login();
  }

  logout() {
    return this.keycloak?.logout();
  }

  hasRole(role: string) {
    return this.keycloak?.hasRealmRole(role);
  }
}

Here's my Dockerfile for the Angular app:
FROM node:alpine AS build

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

RUN npm run build -- --configuration production

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=build /app/dist/jtekt-client/browser /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]


Here's my Nginx configuration (nginx.conf):
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # Security headers
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
}

What I've Tried:
Ensured the VM is accessible from the host machine.
Confirmed that Keycloak is running and accessible at http://192.168.1.105:8080.
Updated the Keycloak configuration in my Angular service to use the VM's IP address.
Checked that the docker-compose.yml is correctly configured to expose the necessary ports.
Question:
Why am I getting a timeout error with the message "Timeout when waiting for 3rd party check iframe message" when trying to access my Angular app on the VM? How can I resolve this issue so that the Keycloak login page is correctly displayed when accessing the Angular app at http://192.168.1.105:4200?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN; comes to mind.  Different localhost ports will be treated as different domains.  I would omit that tag or serve both from same domain.
